Google Cloud Dataflow : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
I'm building a Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline using Python 3.8 to parse data from a pub/sub topic. I followed every tutorial about it, it compiles and launches, but when executed I always get:
LoadMainSessionException: Could not load main session. Inspect which external dependencies are used in the main module of your pipeline. Verify that corresponding packages are installed in the pipeline runtime environment and their installed versions match the versions used in pipeline submission environment. For more information, see: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/ Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py", line 115, in create_harness _load_main_session(semi_persistent_directory) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py", line 354, in _load_main_session pickler.load_session(session_file) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 65, in load_session return desired_pickle_lib.load_session(file_path) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 446, in load_session return dill.load_session(file_path) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 368, in load_session module = unpickler.load() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load obj = StockUnpickler.load(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 827, in _import_module return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'

at ._request_process_bundle ( /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py:331 )
at .run ( /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py:281 )
at .main ( /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py:212 )

I tried adding and removing save_main_session, the error happens at a different time but still there. Here is my tree:
├── Dockerfile
├── Dockerfile.dev
├── cloudbuild.yaml
├── compose.dev.yaml
├── compose.yaml
├── main.py
├── metadata.json
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── launcher.py
│   ├── parser
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── constants.py
│   │   ├── lib.py
│   │   ├── parser_elementor.py
│   │   ├── parser_html.py
│   │   ├── parser_intent.py
│   │   ├── parser_text.py
│   │   ├── template_behavior.py
│   │   └── utilities.py
│   ├── pipeline.py
│   ├── transforms.py
│   └── utilities.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements-test.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── parser_elementor_test.py
    ├── parser_elementor_test_file_1.json
    └── parser_html_test.py

Dockerfile for google cloud:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.8
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

# Copy SDK entrypoint binary from Apache Beam image, which makes it possible to
# use the image as SDK container image. If you explicitly depend on
# apache-beam in setup.py, use the same version of Beam in both files.
COPY --from=apache/beam_python3.11_sdk:2.55.1 /opt/apache/beam /opt/apache/beam

# Copy Flex Template launcher binary from the launcher image, which makes it
# possible to use the image as a Flex Template base image.
COPY --from=gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python311-template-launcher-base:20230622_RC00 /opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher /opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launche

ARG WORKDIR=/app
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    python3-dev \
    libevent-dev

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY setup.py .
COPY main.py .
COPY package package

# Installing exhaustive list of dependencies from a requirements.txt
# helps to ensure that every time Docker container image is built,
# the Python dependencies stay the same. Using `--no-cache-dir` reduces image size.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Installing the pipeline package makes all modules encompassing the pipeline
# available via import statements and installs necessary dependencies.
# Editable installation allows picking up later changes to the pipeline code
# for example during local experimentation within the container.
RUN pip install -e .

# For more informaiton, see: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/main.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE="${WORKDIR}/setup.py"

# Because this image will be used as custom sdk container image, and it already 
# installs the dependencies from the requirements.txt, we can omit
# the FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE directive here
# to reduce pipeline submission time.
# Similarly, since we already installed the pipeline package,
# we don't have to specify the FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE="${WORKDIR}/setup.py" configuration option.

# Optionally, verify that dependencies are not conflicting.
# A conflict may or may not be significant for your pipeline.
RUN pip check

# Optionally, list all installed dependencies.
# The output can be used to seed requirements.txt for reproducible builds.
RUN pip freeze

# Set the entrypoint to Apache Beam SDK launcher, which allows this image
# to be used as an SDK container image.
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/apache/beam/boot"]

cloudbuild.yaml:
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args:
      ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/parsing-pipeline-image:latest", "."]
    dir: "."
    env:
      - "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1"
    id: "Build parsing pipeline image"
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/parsing-pipeline-image:latest"]
    id: "Push parsing image"
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args:
      - dataflow
      - flex-template
      - build
      - gs://reversia-pipelines-templates/reversia-parsing-pipeline.json
      - --image-gcr-path=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/parsing-pipeline-image:latest
      - --sdk-language=PYTHON
      - --flex-template-base-image=PYTHON3
      - --py-path=.
      - --metadata-file=metadata.json
      - --env=FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE=main.py
      - --env=FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE=requirements.txt
    id: "Deploy Dataflow Flex Template"

main.py:
import logging

from package import launcher

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    launcher.run()

setup.py:
"""Defines a Python package for an Apache Beam pipeline."""

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="package",
    version="0.2.0",
    install_requires=[
        "apache-beam[gcp]==2.55.1",  # Must match the version in `Dockerfile``.
        "requests",
        "google-cloud-logging",
        "beautifulsoup4",
        "google-cloud-secret-manager",
        "dataclasses_json",
        "typing_extensions"
    ],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)

package.launcher.py:
"""Defines command line arguments for the pipeline defined in the package."""

import argparse
import os
from typing import List

from package import pipeline


def run(argv: "List[str] | None" = None):
    """Parses the parameters provided on the command line and runs the pipeline."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--reversia_api_url', help='Reversia API URL', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--topic', help='Topic of the data', required=True)

    pipeline_args, other_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    os.environ['REVERSIA_API_URL'] = pipeline_args.reversia_api_url

    parsing_pipeline = pipeline.parsing_pipeline(pipeline_args.topic, other_args)

    parsing_pipeline.run()

package.pipeline.py:
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from typing import List

from package import transforms


def parsing_pipeline(
    topic: str,
    pipeline_options_args: List[str]
):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_options_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True)
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    _ = (
        pipeline
        | 'Read from Pub/Sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic)
        | "Parse raw cntent" >> transforms.Parse()
        .with_output_types(bool)
    )

    return pipeline

package.transforms.py:
import apache_beam as beam
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json, LetterCase
from typing import Dict

from package.api import filter_by_content_fields_hash_diff, update_by_content_hashes_diff
from package.parser.utilities import is_json, contains_html
from package.parser.parser_elementor import parse_elementor
from package.parser.parser_html import parse_html
from package.parser.parser_text import parse_text
from package.utilities import get_secret


@dataclass
@dataclass_json(letter_case=LetterCase.CAMEL) 
class ReceivedElement:
    project_id: str
    language_code: str
    resource: str
    resource_id: str
    hashes: Dict[str, str]
    content: Dict[str, str]

@dataclass
class ParsedElement:
    project_id: str
    language_code: str
    resource: str
    resource_id: str
    parsed_fields: Dict[str, str]

class PreFilterDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        self.agent_api_key = None

    def setup(self):
        self.agent_api_key = get_secret('my_project', 'workflow-payload-api-agent')

    def process(self, encoded_element: bytes):
        element = ReceivedElement.from_json(encoded_element.decode('utf-8'))

        changed_fields = filter_by_content_fields_hash_diff(
            self.agent_api_key,
            element.project_id,
            element.language_code,
            element.resource, 
            element.id, 
            element.hashes
        )

        if changed_fields:
            element.content.update({field: element.content[field] for field in changed_fields})

            yield element

class ParseDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element: ReceivedElement):
        parsed_fields = {}

        for field, content in element.content.items():
            if is_json(content):
                parsed_content = parse_elementor(content)
            elif contains_html(content):
                parsed_content = parse_html(content)
            else:
                parsed_content = parse_text(content)

            parsed_fields[field] = parsed_content

        yield {
            'project_id': element.project_id,
            'language_code': element.language_code,
            'resource': element.resource,
            'resource_id': element.resource_id,
            'parsed_fields': parsed_fields
        }

class SendDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        self.agent_api_key = None

    def setup(self):
        self.agent_api_key = get_secret('my_project', 'workflow-payload-api-agent')

    def process(self, element: ParsedElement):
        yield update_by_content_hashes_diff(
            self.agent_api_key,
            element.project_id,
            element.language_code,
            element.resource, 
            element.resource_id, 
            element.parsed_fields
        )

class Parse(beam.PTransform):
    """A composite transform that takes a PCollection of encoded elements"""

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (
            pcoll
            | 'Pre filter Data' >> beam.ParDo(PreFilterDoFn())
            | 'Parse Data' >> beam.ParDo(ParseDoFn())
            | 'Send to API' >> beam.ParDo(SendDoFn())
        )

I specified everything into the setup.py as described in the beam and dataflow doc, but still, it doesn't seem to take it into account.

are you following https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/dataflow/flex-templates/pipeline_with_dependencies? gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python311-template-launcher-base is not correct since you use python 3.8.
